# WordPress is declaring JQuery in the Footer

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, google-tag-manager

I've been handed a WordPress (WP) site from a 3rd party. I work with Drupal, so I'm not well-rounded in WP.

That said, I'm attempting to install Google Tag Manager (GTM). However, I'm getting console errors, stating that JQuery is not defined. I've discovered that JQuery is defined in the `<footer>`, not the `<head>`. I've had this issue in the past with Drupal, but I'm not sure where to begin with WP.

After looking at the template, I've discovered that there is a `<?php wp_head(); ?>` tag in the head and there is a `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` tag in the footer. Both tags inject scripts, but obviously, JQuery is injected through the footer tag. From what I can tell, the scripts are compiled in the script-loader.php document, but the document is a little overwhelming. I'm not exactly sure what to move around in order to get JQuery injected through the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` tag.

I've uploaded the [script-loader.php document to Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Qy8XMxgmnGMWtWd0NCbWQxbkE/view?usp=sharing). I'll put it into a .txt file so that it's readable within GDrive.

Please let me know if there's anything else I can provide. Any helpful feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting on the Stack Exchange site for WordPress, [I found a solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/261805/jquery-needs-to-be-defined-in-head-but-gravity-forms-is-defining-it-in-the-f). Basically, I had to enqueue the GTM script, declaring JQuery as a dependency to it. The script I was provided is as follows:

```
function my_theme_add_gtm_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('google-track-manager', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/gtm.js', array('jquery'), false, false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_add_gtm_script');
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to register and en-queue scripts in wordpress, you don't place them in the header/footer yourself.

there is a functions.php file in the theme template folder, inside there may be a function calling the wp_enqueue_scripts hook, search for that and modify it before creating a new one.

if not, add something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'includes', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/includes.js?v=2', array(
        'jquery',
        'jquery-ui-core'
    ), '1.0', true );
}
```

but replace my third enqueue "includes" with your GTM include, or just delete it. that will make sure jQuery and jQuery UI are loaded at the correct time. the third option makes sure they are loaded before loading my includes.php

Comment: Should I place your function inside this if statement? 
`if ( apply_filters( 'wp_auth_check_load', $show, $screen ) ) {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-auth-check' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-auth-check' );

  add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'wp_auth_check_html', 5 );
  add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'wp_auth_check_html', 5 );}`

Comment: no i would add it as a separate function, as it uses a separate hook. also you don't want it to be dependent on the apply_filters logic, but rather running every time regardless.

Comment: So, I tried deleting the third line. Is this what you had in mind: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
}` It doesn't seem to be working, so I'm question whether or not I have it right.

Comment: that looks right. could you give more detail to the method you are using to install GTM?

Comment: I'm using a module called **Head, Footer and Post Injections**. It basically allows me to inject the GTM `<script>` tag into the head, and the `<noscript>` tag immediately after the `<body>`.

Comment: I discovered that I was inserting the function into the wrong functions.php document. I tried it in the correct document, but I'm still not having any luck.  I did notice that an add_action already exists for wp_enque_script. See below: `function ff_modify_jquery() {
 if (!is_admin()) {
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  // wp_register_script('jquery', 
  wp_register_script('jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/application.js', false, '2.1.4', true);
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ff_modify_jquery');`